# ActiveRecord::UnknownAttributeError at /line_items

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

Creating my own ecommerce app alongside Agile 4's tutorial ecommerce app. Getting the following error after clicking "add to cart".

**ActiveRecord::UnknownAttributeError at /line_items
unknown attribute: cart_id**

BetterErrors highlights the starred line of my line_items controller#create code:

```
def create
@cart = current_cart
product = Product.find(params[:product_id])
**@line_item = @cart.line_items.build(:product_id => product.id)**
```

I have cart_id in my application controller code as requested by the book:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  protect_from_forgery

  private

 def current_cart 
   Cart.find(session[:cart_id])
 rescue ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound
   cart = Cart.create
   session[:cart_id] = cart.id
   cart
 end
end
```

-and in my carts table as cart_id:integer in schema.

Let me know if there's any more code I can copy that would help lead to an answer.

Thank you.

Comment: How are your carts and line items associated? That's what the error is about.

Comment: If your `associations` are set correctly,you should be having `cart_id` in your `line_items` table.Do you have it?

Comment: That let me to a new error, so it worked.  Thanks guys, I'm not sure how to crown you for points via comments @Pavan

Comment: can you share your related db schema?